# Reading an Array elements from a variable of object type in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have an array of integers that contains contains value like ["1" "2" "4" "5" "8"].
I read this array in an object. Now I would like to get this values in a comma separated string.
I am using c#. .NET library is 4.0.

I am trying to use the following snippet

```
int[] array = new int[] { 0, 1, 2 };
object obj=array;
IEnumerable<object> collection = (IEnumerable<object>)obj;

foreach (object item in collection)
{
    output = output + "," + item.ToString() ;
}
```

I get the following error -> unable to cast System.Int32[] to System.collection.Generic.IEnumerable

Any advice?

Comment: Just use `string.Join(",", array)`

Comment: `obj` is `int[]`. Hence you must cast it to int array.

Comment: `var collection = (IEnumerable)obj;` should work. Not a generic version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int[] array = new int[] { 0, 1, 2 };
object obj=array;

var collection = (IEnumerable<int>)obj;

string result = string.Join(",", collection); // works.
```

Note that I'm casting to the actual type of the array elements.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you doing such a thing? An int is already an object.

```
int[] array = new int[] { 0, 1, 2 };
var output = string.Join(",", array);
```

EDIT: Probably you are misleading people saying you get that as object. Where you get it, make it IEnumerable.

```
void Main()
{
  int[] array = new int[] { 0, 1, 2 };
  Console.WriteLine(GetAsString(array));    
    
}

public string GetAsString<T>(IEnumerable<T> x)
{
    return string.Join(",", x);
}
```

Comment: "An int is already an object" is an oversimplified statement.  `int` is treated like a *value* (until it isn't), and if `int`s were objects in all circumstances, boxing wouldn't be a thing.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I don't understand what do you mean. Are you saying it is not an object?

Comment: I am saying it is not treated like an object (until it is).  In Java, this distinction is made clear by having separate types for `int` and `Integer`, where `Integer` is the object, and `int` is a primitive type.

Comment: @Cetin Basoz - This integer array I am getting as an object, returned by another program. I was trying to simulate that in this code. That's why I was trying to manipulate.

Comment: @SabyasachiMukherjee, I don't understand what you mean either, sorry. Simply use string.Join(",", yourIEnumerable<T>) as I showed.

Comment: @CetinBasoz: It would be more accurate to say that `int` can be upcast to `object` (If I'm saying that right).  Or, in code: `int is object` evaluates to true.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, why do you need some up\downcasting here! Why do you think string.Join(",", array) wouldn't work at all?

Comment: @CetinBasoz: `string.Join` won't work on `object`, because it doesn't contain an enumerator.  The OP says he's receiving the array as an `object`.  It's not the first time this has happened; the .NET framework does this all the time.  I think it's a holdout from the days when they didn't have generics.

Comment: There's no insult intended.  I see the problem that the OP is trying to solve.  You haven't solved it with your answer, that's all.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, it is solved. Try passing an int[] to a routine where that routine returns the ints in the array as a comma separated value.

Comment: @CetinBasoz: The OP is not getting it as an `int[]`; they're getting it as an `object`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, In his question he has int[] array = ...

Comment: Because they're trying to simulate an array of `int[]` in an object for this question's purposes.